Use VBA to assign an ascending number to items, but same number to duplicates
In my sheet for work I have to assign numbers to products that need to be assembled.
These numbers will later correspond with blueprints/cad drawings.
When there are duplicates the need to have the same "cad number".
Also, some products are ordered so dont need assembly.
This is a smaller example of a list:



Number
Item
Length
Width
Height




Room 1






z
Table
100
100
100


z
Chair
100
100
200


z
Chair
100
100
100



Lamp
100
100
100


Room 2






z
Table
100
100
100


z
Table
100
200
100


z
Chair
100
100
100



After the macro it should be:



Number
Item
Length
Width
Height




Room 1






1
Table
100
100
100


2
Chair
100
100
200


3
Chair
100
100
100



Lamp
100
100
100


Room 2






1
Table
100
100
100


4
Table
100
200
100


3
Chair
100
100
100



I use the "z" to manually pick which products need assembly.
I've tried it with multiple columns of formulas.
The first to concantate the last 4 columns.
The second column a formula with countif to spot the duplicates.
The third column has a formula to get the previous number and add 1 or if column 2 says true then "dupe" so i can manually get the right number.
Basicly it takes away 2 of the 4 steps.
Because i need to concantate, countif and somehow have an array of already used number and "concat" combo's its a bit too difficult to start from scratch.
I really want to learn so thats why Im trying to get this with VBA instead of multiple columns of formulas. Also because the file gets send to customers.

Please provide the code that you have tried in your post (press edit and add).  Note that this is not a code-for-you service; SO will aid in resolving a specific issue.

if you're looking for a starting place, i would recommend finding a match, if the match exists, then assign previous number; else append a value (i=i+1).

Thank you for your comment. I added an answer now, does that suffice for your first comment? Thanks for helping me on this site!

So after looking at my macro for half an hour, i came to this conclusion:
For Each c In rngNmbr
If c.value = "z" Then
    'InputValue is all details concanated
    Inputvalue = c.Offset(, 5) & c.Offset(, 6) & c.Offset(, 7) & c.Offset(, 8) & c.Offset(, 9)
    If inArray(arr, Inputvalue) Then
        For i = 0 To 2000
            If arr(i, 0) = Inputvalue Then
                c.value = arr(i, 1)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Else
        c.value = n + 1
        arr(n, 0) = Inputvalue
        arr(n, 1) = c.value
        n = n + 1
    End If
End If
Next

Also I should mention that this code is in an Add-in that I made myself so the workbook itself is still a .xlsx
Thank you for the answers but for now this works a dream.

This code generates the required numbering to the specific arrangement of the data in the sample table
Sub sequ()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet5")
lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ReDim context(2 To lastrow)
For i = 2 To lastrow
  If ws.Cells(i, "B") <> "" Then
   context(i) = ws.Cells(i, "B") & ws.Cells(i, "C") & ws.Cells(i, "D") & ws.Cells(i, "E")
  End If
Next i
counter = 1
For i = 2 To lastrow
  For j = 2 To i
    If context(i) = context(j) And Cells(i, "A") = "z" And context(i) <> "" And i = j Then
      Cells(i, "A") = counter
      counter = counter + 1
    ElseIf context(i) = context(j) And context(i) <> "" Then
      Cells(i, "A") = Cells(j, "A")
    End If
  Next j
Next i
End Sub



Alternative with PowerQuery making it easier to send to clients (no need for xlsm extention)

Select the source table and go to data > from table range

in PQ click on Advanced editor and paste:
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Item", type text}, {"Length", type text}, {"Width", type text}, {"Height", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "ID", each if [Number] = null then null else if [Number] = "z" then [Item]&[Length]&[Width]&[Height] else [Number]),

    Grouping = 
        let
            #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([Number] = "z")),
            #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"ID"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}}),
            #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
            #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Index",{"Count"})
        in
            #"Removed Columns" ,

    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Custom", {"ID"}, Grouping, {"ID"}, "Group", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Group" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Group", {"Index"}, {"Index"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Group",{"Number"}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Number", each if [Index] = null then [ID] else [Index]),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Item", "Length", "Width", "Height", "Number"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Other Columns",{"Number", "Item", "Length", "Width", "Height"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Reordered Columns",{{"Length", Int64.Type}, {"Width", Int64.Type}, {"Height", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"


Click on Close & Load


The result will be loaded to a new table in a new sheet. You could hide the source sheet or add some minor changes to load the source from CSV so it's not loaded in the result workbook ready to be send.

Looks very advanced. Thanks for your anwser but I came up with a rather easy solution myself.

I do want to add that i will come back to this in the future, whenever im ready for a new challange!
